# Wpf Listview Stretch

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, store, stretch

I would like to have, as you can see from the code, 3 pairs of textblock, listview to fit the hight of my screen. 
The problem is that as new listviewitems get in the scrollviewer instead of remaining the same and adding the Vertical scroll, it grows and gets out of the 1/3 I gave to it.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" Background="#FF696969" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <ListView x:Name="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,17,0"/>
               </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Grid>
...
```

P.S
For those who have problems with the ListView "eating" the 1st character when selected you can use:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,17,0"/>
      </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Vertical scroll appears on adding new item. What issue you are facing?

Comment: Agreed on the scrollbar appearing, do you have any default styles or templates applied?

Comment: if for example purposes the ScrollViewer box is 500px and each ListViewItem is 100px (Height) when i add the 6th ListViewItem i want the ScrollViewer size to remain 500 and have verticalScroll, instead with this code i will have the ScrollViewer resize to 600px
EDIT: the scrollbar appears but its not usefull

Comment: You can reproduce this in a brand new app with only the xaml you have listed and adding items to the ListView directly (i.e. `this.list.Items.Add("Item1")`?  Even directly setting the Height of the items, or the ScrollViewer, works fine for me.  I'm wondering if there's something else in your application.

Comment: @StefanosC you don't need to put `ListView` inside `ScrollViewer`. It already handles scrolling and by putting it inside `ScrollViewer` you loose virtualization. Remove `ScrollViewer` and put `ListView` directly into your `Grid` and this may even solve your scrollbar issue.

Comment: @dkozl I need the Scroll bar because the list will have more items than the Height i want
tencntraze You are right, when i copy the grid in a blank doc it works, i dont know why though, i add the items the same way in my program

Comment: What the container for outer `Grid`? It all seems as container for outer the `Grid` expands

Comment: Horizontal ScrollViewer->Grid->Grid

Comment: It's the outer ScrollViewer that is causing the problem, is there another way to have my content have horizontal scroll without putting everything inside a ScrollViewer?

Comment: @StefanosC, how do you hide vertical scrollbar in that `ScrollViewer`? By `Hide` or `Disable`?

Comment: the top ScrollViewer is Disabled and Hidden, and the list one is Enabled and Visible, but i tried all combinations and they are not working

Comment: I managed to "fix" it by adding MaxHeight to each ListView but that's not the correct way to do it for scalability reasons. One idea is to calculate manually the 1*-Titlesize for each ListView but not sure if it will work.

Comment: @StefanosC you mentioned that your two `Grid`s are in a horizontal `ScrollViewer`. I've asked you what you set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to to disable vertical scrolling? Is it `Disabled` or `Hidden`? Both will hide scroll bar but in latter case elements will still be able to grow vertically, exactly what seems to be happening in your case

Comment: It is set to Hidden, but i tried all the combinations of the VerticalScrollBarVisibility & VerticalScrollMode for the 2 ScrollViewers